Multiple defparameter macro in Lisp?
I tried to write defparameter macro for arbitrary number of variables, starting from the working code for the single variable:
(defmacro defpar (name initial-value )                                                  
 `(progn (declaim (special ,name))                                                    
        (setf (symbol-value ',name) ,initial-value)                                  
         ',name)

Here is a modification
(defmacro defpar (&rest rest)
  (let ((i  (gensym)))
    `(let (,i)
;;     (declaim (special ,rest))
       (dotimes (,i  (/ (length ',rest) 2))
         (progn
           (print (list ,i ',rest))
           (setf (symbol-value ',(pop rest)) ',(pop rest))
           )
         ))))

Now:
(defpar S1 1)                                                                            
(print `("S1 = " ,S1))

gives
(0 (S1 1)) 
("S1 = " 1)

It is OK: S1 is defined and is equal to 1
and for two arguments
(defpar S1 1 S2 2)                                                                    
(print `("S1 = " ,S1  " S2 = " ,S2 )) 

gives
(0 (*S1* 1 *S2* 2))
(1 (*S1* 1 *S2* 2))
....  The variable *S2* is unbound.   

As I checked, rest list is the same at the new iteration in the loop, but I failed to update it. And I missed the special statement. (declaim (special ,rest)) comes to error in SBCL. Let me know if it is important.
Please, help me. May be it is already done, like in setf?

My answer does not work if the macro is called like this: (defpar-multiple x (+ 1 2)) because my answer does not evaluate the (+ 1 2) whereas if you call (defparameter x (+1 2)), then x will get set to 3.

I would name it defparameters

Just generate multiple defparameter forms?
CL-USER 8 > (defmacro defpar (&rest var-and-value-list)
              `(progn ,@(loop for (var value) on var-and-value-list by #'cddr
                              collect `(defparameter ,var ,value))))
DEFPAR

CL-USER 9 > (pprint (macroexpand '(defpar a 1 b 2 c 3)))

(PROGN (DEFPARAMETER A 1)
       (DEFPARAMETER B 2)
       (DEFPARAMETER C 3))

The DEFPARAMETER expansion details varies between CL implementations
Keep in mind that the macro expansion of DEFPARAMETER is not standardized in Common Lisp. Different implementations expand that into different forms. Many of them are also implementation specific. Additionally the expansion may provide features of a development environment, like recording the source code or recording the location of the source code. Thus it is best not to reinvent defparameter for multiple forms, but to reuse it. This makes sure that the implementation specific feature are still supported.

Thank you! Fantastic, it is even possible to insert comments for individual variables in the call of macro! Very useful when you have pages of variables)

@Maxim Do you need pages of variables? I'm curious now

why not?) it is usual situation in physical models.. that is why i asked the question..

as I understand,  here we can also use documentation, implemented in  defparameter if needed.

Strange, that change of defparameter to defvar operator in the macro does not change behavior: we still can change variable any time we want using setf. Of course, we can check using boundp weather variable is already defined, but I would expect that defvar should do it.

@Maxim DEFPARAMETER or DEFVAR have no limiting influence on updates via SETF.

No good!  See comments.
This works for me:
(defmacro defpar-multiple (&rest varname-val-list)
  `(loop for (varname val) on ',varname-val-list by #'cddr
         collect varname
         do
            ;;(format t "~a = ~a~%" varname val)
            (setf (symbol-value varname) val)))     
           

In the repl:
CL-USER> (defpar-multiple aaa 2 bbb 3)

That expands to:
(loop for (varname val) on '(aaa 2 bbb 3) by #'cddr
      collect varname
      do (setf (symbol-value varname) val))

And evaluating:
CL-USER> aaa
; Debugger entered on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE AAA {700756DAD3}>

[1] CL-USER> bbb
; Debugger entered on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE BBB {70079BB643}>

CL-USER> (defpar-multiple aaa 2 bbb 3)
(AAA BBB)

CL-USER> aaa
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)

CL-USER> bbb
3 (2 bits, #x3, #o3, #b11)

CL-USER> 

I'm not sure why I have to write:
(setf (symbol-value varname) val)

instead of:
(setf varname val)

but the latter does not survive compile time.
Edited code:
(defmacro defpar-multiple (&rest varname-val-list)
  `(loop for (varname val) on ',varname-val-list by #'cddr
         for evaled-val = (eval val)
         collect varname
         do  ;;(format t "~a = ~a~%" varname evaled-val)
             (setf (symbol-value varname) evaled-val)))

Then
CL-USER> (defpar-multiple att 0 gtt (+ 1 4))

expands to:
(loop for (varname val) on '(att 0 gtt (+ 1 4)) by #'cddr
      for evaled-val = (eval val)
      collect varname
      do (setf (symbol-value varname) evaled-val))

Evaluating:
CL-USER> att
; Debugger entered on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE ATT {7007340F13}>

CL-USER> gtt
; Debugger entered on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE GTT {700779AAF3}>

CL-USER> (defpar-multiple att 0 gtt (+ 1 4))
(ATT GTT)

CL-USER> att
0 (0 bits, #x0, #o0, #b0)

CL-USER> gtt
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)

CL-USER> 


(defpar-multiple a (+ 1 2)) -> A = (+ 1 2)

(setf varname val) sets the variable varname to the value of the variable var. Do you want that?

@RainerJoswig, No!  Editing my answer, so the op can change the check mark to your answer.

@RainerJoswig, Can I simply add (eval val), so that instead of setting the variable to (+ 1 4) the variable is set to 5?  I added some code with an eval to the bottom of my answer.

Expanding to a  loop isn't such a great solution. It might lead to smaller code if there were hundreds of variable? Maybe. Rainer Joswig's answer nails it: just produce a progn with defparameter forms.  The eval is poor. It's possible to do better. We can separate the symbols and variables: e.g. (a 1 b 2 c 3) can be turne dinto (quote (a b c)) and (list 1 2 3) .  We let these expressions be evaluated naturally by inserting them into the code template and then walk them in parallel for sym in '(a b c) and for val in (list 1 2 3).

The background idea is that you have a large set of parameters, and of course you want to minimise the code, exclude extra defparametrs etc. I think the most important here is readibility of the code. Then pairs of Name-Value with comment is the best choice, at least for some problems)

@7stud: the question of EVAL is always: in which environment do I evaluate (interpreted or compiled ?) the form? One example: (let ((a 10)) (defpar-multiple b a)) for example would not work for the local variable a.
